# How do I round only the top two corners of a UILabel?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uilabel

I know that in iOS 3.0+ I can use

```
 label.layer.cornerRadius = xxx;
```

to round all four corners of a UILabel (as a UIView subclass), but I want to round only the top two corners of the label and keep the bottom corners right-angled.

Is there any way I can do that with a UILabel? Other solutions assume a custom UIView, not a UILabel.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can do this using CALayers and masks

```
CAShapeLayer *maskLayer = [CAShapeLayer layer];
maskLayer.path = maskPath.CGPath;
label.layer.mask = maskLayer;
```

where maskPath is a UIBezierPath set up using `bezierPathWithRoundedRect:byRoundingCorners:cornerRadii`

Comment: i think it should be label.layer.mask = maskLayer

Comment: accepted this answer as I did not want to use an extra view here. I am using two overlaying layers with the bottom layer all rounded, and the top layer with only top two corners rounded. To give this effect http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/walrick/openphone/256/Calendar-icon.png

Answer (score 29):

Thought I would post the full code with the BezierPath included.

```
CGRect bounds = label.bounds;
UIBezierPath *maskPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:bounds
                                                                   byRoundingCorners:(UIRectCornerTopLeft | UIRectCornerTopRight)
                                                                         cornerRadii:CGSizeMake(5.0, 5.0)];

CAShapeLayer *maskLayer = [CAShapeLayer layer];
maskLayer.frame = bounds;
maskLayer.path = maskPath.CGPath;

label.layer.mask = maskLayer;
```

**For Swift 4.0:**

```
let bounds: CGRect = label.bounds
let maskPath = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: bounds, byRoundingCorners: ([.topLeft, .topRight]), cornerRadii: CGSize(width: 5.0, height: 5.0))
let maskLayer = CAShapeLayer()
maskLayer.frame = bounds
maskLayer.path = maskPath.cgPath
label.layer.mask = maskLayer
```

Answer (score 1):

I have checked the Class Reference for UIView & UILabel and its layers, but could not find any way to do this with the means given by the iOS.

You could do one thing, create a `UIView` & apply rounded corners to it. Now add a `UILabel` as a subview to this UIView & position it in such a way so that the bottom 2 rounded corners are covered by the label. This way you get the effect you need...

Comment: and make sure that UIView and UILabel have same colour.