# How can I make angled corners on a UIView?

Tags: ios, uiview, core-graphics

There's LOTS of questions on here about making a `UIView`'s corners rounded. Unfortunately I can't find anything for how to make *angled* corners. How can I make a `UIView` with corners cut at a 45 degree angle instead?

You can even have a bonus (figurative) gold star if you can show me how to make *any individual* corner cut at an angle.

Edit: For reference, [here's a link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9034328/how-do-i-round-only-the-top-two-corners-of-a-uilabel/) to a question that I suspect has a similar implementation to this solution. I just don't know what I'd have to change.

Comment: IIRC CoreGraphics does the job if you make pixels transparent. Did you try that?

Comment: @H2CO3 I'm not really sure what you mean by that. Do you mean to use an image with clipped corners as the background color?

Comment: @Tahne No, I mean drawing transparent pixels programmatically using the `CGContext*()` functions.

Comment: @H2CO3 Actually, I haven't tried that, and I'm not even sure how to do it. If you know how, I'd be interested in seeing an answer below. :)

Comment: I'm not brave enough :) I'm not being a Quartz super-freak and I don't know that off the top of my head, and anyway it's 1AM here, but if you wait a few hours I'll see what I can do...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First you need a path with the angled corners:

```
- (CGPathRef) makeAnglePathWithRect: (CGRect)rect withSize:(float) s {

    CGPoint one = CGPointMake( rect.origin.x +s, rect.origin.y);
    CGPoint two = CGPointMake( rect.origin.x + rect.size.width - s, rect.origin.y);

    CGPoint three = CGPointMake( rect.origin.x + rect.size.width, rect.origin.y +s);
    CGPoint four = CGPointMake( rect.origin.x + rect.size.width, rect.origin.y + rect.size.height -s);

    CGPoint five = CGPointMake( rect.origin.x + rect.size.width-s, rect.origin.y + rect.size.height);
    CGPoint six = CGPointMake(rect.origin.x+s, rect.origin.y + rect.size.height);

    CGPoint seven = CGPointMake(rect.origin.x, rect.origin.y + rect.size.height-s);
    CGPoint eight = CGPointMake(rect.origin.x, rect.origin.y + s);

    CGMutablePathRef path = CGPathCreateMutable();
    CGPathMoveToPoint(path,NULL,one.x, one.y);
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(path,NULL,two.x, two.y);
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(path,NULL,three.x, three.y);
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(path,NULL,four.x, four.y);
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(path,NULL,five.x, five.y);
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(path,NULL,six.x, six.y);
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(path,NULL,seven.x, seven.y);
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(path,NULL,eight.x, eight.y);
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(path,NULL,one.x, one.y);

    return path;
}
```

Then you need to use the path to specify a mask:

```
CAShapeLayer *maskLayer = [CAShapeLayer layer];
CGRect bounds = CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, 100, 100); //figure out your bounds

[maskLayer setFrame:bounds];
CGPathRef p = [self makeAnglePathWithRect:bounds withSize:20.0];
maskLayer.path = p;
_myview.layer.mask = maskLayer;
```

If you want to remove the angles from any corner, fiddle with points one-eight, removing the "s" value. You can change the size of the triangles cut out of the corners with the size parameter.

Comment: Accepting this solution because even though it's longer, I think it's much more customizable. If you're going to do all the corners, you should probably check out the other answer.

Comment: I hereby award my figurative gold star! :)

Comment: Thanks! I considered code-golfing it by putting the points in an array and looping over them for the CGPathAddLineToPoint, but decided to leave it as it is for the purposes of clarity.

Comment: ABSOLUTE GENIUS!! AMAZING :)

Answer (score 4):

Taking inspiration from @nont and using extension, I write this snippet:

```
extension UIView {

    public enum Corner: Int {
        case TopRight
        case TopLeft
        case BottomRight
        case BottomLeft
        case All
    }

    public func blendCorner(corner corner: Corner, length: CGFloat = 20.0) {
        let maskLayer = CAShapeLayer()
        var path: CGPathRef?
        switch corner {
        case .All:
            path = self.makeAnglePathWithRect(self.bounds, topLeftSize: length, topRightSize: length, bottomLeftSize: length, bottomRightSize: length)
        case .TopRight:
            path = self.makeAnglePathWithRect(self.bounds, topLeftSize: 0.0, topRightSize: length, bottomLeftSize: 0.0, bottomRightSize: 0.0)
        case .TopLeft:
            path = self.makeAnglePathWithRect(self.bounds, topLeftSize: length, topRightSize: 0.0, bottomLeftSize: 0.0, bottomRightSize: 0.0)
        case .BottomRight:
            path = self.makeAnglePathWithRect(self.bounds, topLeftSize: 0.0, topRightSize: 0.0, bottomLeftSize: 0.0, bottomRightSize: length)
        case .BottomLeft:
            path = self.makeAnglePathWithRect(self.bounds, topLeftSize: 0.0, topRightSize: 0.0, bottomLeftSize: length, bottomRightSize: 0.0)
        }
        maskLayer.path = path
        self.layer.mask = maskLayer
    }

    private func makeAnglePathWithRect(rect: CGRect, topLeftSize tl: CGFloat, topRightSize tr: CGFloat, bottomLeftSize bl: CGFloat, bottomRightSize br: CGFloat) -> CGPathRef {
        var points = [CGPoint]()

        points.append(CGPointMake(rect.origin.x + tl, rect.origin.y))
        points.append(CGPointMake(rect.origin.x + rect.size.width - tr, rect.origin.y))
        points.append(CGPointMake(rect.origin.x + rect.size.width, rect.origin.y + tr))
        points.append(CGPointMake(rect.origin.x + rect.size.width, rect.origin.y + rect.size.height - br))
        points.append(CGPointMake(rect.origin.x + rect.size.width - br, rect.origin.y + rect.size.height))
        points.append(CGPointMake(rect.origin.x + bl, rect.origin.y + rect.size.height))
        points.append(CGPointMake(rect.origin.x, rect.origin.y + rect.size.height - bl))
        points.append(CGPointMake(rect.origin.x, rect.origin.y + tl))

        let path = CGPathCreateMutable()
        CGPathMoveToPoint(path, nil, points.first!.x, points.first!.y)
        for point in points {
            if point != points.first {
                CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, nil, point.x, point.y)
            }
        }
        CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, nil, points.first!.x, points.first!.y)
        return path
    }

}
```

In this way you can easily blend your corner:

```
let view = UIView()
view.blendCorner(corner: .TopRight)
// or view.blendCorner(corner: .All)
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is one way to do it. Given:

`const CGFloat kRadius = 20.0; //'radius' of the corner clip`

and given this property in your view:

`@property (nonatomic,strong) CAShapeLayer *maskLayer;`

you can set up a simple mask layer with a beveled line join (giving you the 45 degree angle you want very easily):

```
CAShapeLayer *maskLayer = [CAShapeLayer layer];

maskLayer.lineWidth = kRadius * 2.0;
maskLayer.lineJoin = kCALineJoinBevel;
maskLayer.strokeColor = [[UIColor blackColor] CGColor];

self.layer.mask = self.maskLayer = maskLayer;
```

Then at the appropriate time (say in your `-[ViewClass layoutSublayersOfLayer:]`) just set the path of your mask layer to a rectangular path inset by the radius:

`self.maskLayer.path = CGPathCreateWithRect(CGRectInset(self.bounds,kRadius,kRadius), NULL);`

That's one way to do this without having to resort to drawing each section of the path by hand. You're essentially using the bevel line join to do that bit of work for you.

Comment: This is an excellent solution! Is there any way to get it to work with any one of the corners?