# rounded corner uilabel not visible (xcode 4.5.2)

Tags: ios

I am new to IOS development, try to create top rounded corner label
by following link
[How do I round only the top two corners of a UILabel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9034328/how-do-i-round-only-the-top-two-corners-of-a-uilabel)
But after applying the mask, the whole label cannot be seen, Any clue?
Here is my code.

```
@synthesize title;
- (void)viewDidLoad
{

    [super viewDidLoad];
    title.layer.borderColor=[[UIColor blueColor]CGColor];
    title.layer.borderWidth=2;
    UIBezierPath *maskPath;
    maskPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:title.bounds byRoundingCorners:(UIRectCornerTopLeft | UIRectCornerTopRight) cornerRadii:CGSizeMake(10.0f, 10.0f)];
    CAShapeLayer *maskLayer = [CAShapeLayer layer];
    maskLayer.frame=title.bounds;
    maskLayer.path = maskPath.CGPath;
    title.layer.mask = maskLayer;
}
```

**EDITED**

Tried the suggestion to create the label in program, the layout become

https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B60xg2ZCEjOqeTBEWG92N0NodFU/edit?usp=sharing
The corner disappear and I still want to set the mask the "title" labal?

**EDITED**
Finally give up, for others benefit,I wrap the label in uiview , map the uiview to a class (i.e. Myview.m), and put the same code in method "- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect{}" in "Myview.m".  The display showed as what I want!.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is your problem because you didn't show how the `title` label is created, but if you're creating it in code, you need to be sure to alloc/init the label, as well as give it a frame and then add it as a subview of its superview.

```
title = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(100.0f, 100.0f, 60.0f, 30.0f)];

title.layer.borderColor=[[UIColor blueColor]CGColor];
title.layer.borderWidth=2;
UIBezierPath *maskPath;
maskPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:title.bounds byRoundingCorners:(UIRectCornerTopLeft | UIRectCornerTopRight) cornerRadii:CGSizeMake(10.0f, 10.0f)];
CAShapeLayer *maskLayer = [CAShapeLayer layer];
maskLayer.frame=title.bounds;
maskLayer.path = maskPath.CGPath;
title.layer.mask = maskLayer;

[self.view addSubview:title];
```

Comment: title is not created in code. It is created in storyboard view ,and referenced in .h "IBOutlet UILabel *title;"

Comment: I guess so, if only 2 lines code remaining-
title.layer.borderColor=[[UIColor blueColor]CGColor];
title.layer.borderWidth=2; 

It can show blue border with corresponding text.

Answer (score 0):

first of all my advice is don't use "title" as a UILabel name because all UIViewController has a property that name is title.

After changing label name and sure IBOutlet is connected add this code:

```
    lblTitle.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
```

---

I just figure out if you create a label on storyboard you dont need to alloc again. I wrote this code and it works;

```
_L_corner.layer.borderColor =[[UIColor blueColor] CGColor];
_L_corner.layer.borderWidth = 5.0f;
_L_corner.layer.cornerRadius = 3.0f;
```

Comment: Thanks NevzatR, still not see the label.

Comment: I edited my answer please check out, I just wrote it and it works %100.

Comment: NevzatR, I just need top 2 corners rounded, the suggested code showed 4 corners rounded, and if applying the mask, the whole label still cannot be seen.

Comment: Sorry about misunderstood; I try it now and unfortunately topLeft and topRight cornered include border. Therefore topLeft and topRight of label is not shown but if you remove border thats ok. You really need give a border?

Answer (score 0):

Finally give up, for others benefit, and used another work around:-
1) wrap the label in uiview , 
2) map the uiview to a class (i.e. Myview.m), 
3) put the same code in method

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect{
title.layer.borderColor=[[UIColor blueColor]CGColor];
title.layer.borderWidth=2;
UIBezierPath *maskPath;
maskPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:title.bounds byRoundingCorners:(UIRectCornerTopLeft | UIRectCornerTopRight) cornerRadii:CGSizeMake(10.0f, 10.0f)];
CAShapeLayer *maskLayer = [CAShapeLayer layer];
maskLayer.frame=title.bounds;
maskLayer.path = maskPath.CGPath;
title.layer.mask = maskLayer;
```

}
 in "Myview.m". 
The display showed as what I want!